# How to get the active window using X11/Xlib c api?

Tags: c, window, x11, xlib

I cannot find in the [The Xlib Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/) how to get the active window?

Is it the "focus window" that I obtain using [XGetInputFocus](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGetInputFocus.html)?

Or should I query the root window property `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`?
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints#Root_window_properties), this property "gives the currently active window".

So I wanted to use the function [XGetWindowProperty](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html) to get the property `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`, but I have no idea what value I should give to parameters that I do not understand like `long_offset`, `long_length`, `delete`, `req_type`...

I am using Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: There is no notion of active window in X11. Focus is the closest notion (it is the window that receives the keyboard input).  (Some) window managers support the notion of active window and (some of those) let you query one with _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW. Now the question arises, what do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XGetWindowProperty(
    Display *display; //display object, e.g. via XopenDisplay(NULL)
    Window w;         //root window, e.g. via DefaultRootWindow(display)
    Atom property;    //the requested property, here: _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW
    long long_offset; //offset into returned data (32 bit quantity)
    long long_length; //length of data to return (32 bit quantity)
    Bool delete;      //False (as long you don't want to delete the property)
    Atom req_type;    //what type we expect, here we expect a window: XA_WINDOW
    Atom *actual_type_return; //an Atom or any XA_* of what is actually returned
    int *actual_format_return; //depends, read the spec of what will be returned, here: 32
    unsigned long *nitems_return; //how many items are returned, we expect 1
    unsigned long *bytes_after_return; //important on partial read
    unsigned char **prop_return; //pointer to the items
);
```

**Example:**

```
//open default display
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
//get default root window of display
Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
//get the atom of the property
Atom property = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW", False); 

//return values
Atom type_return;
int format_return;
unsigned long nitems_return;
unsigned long bytes_left;
unsigned char *data;

XGetWindowProperty(
    display,
    root,
    property,
    0,              //no offset
    1,              //one Window
    False,
    XA_WINDOW,
    &type_return,   //should be XA_WINDOW
    &format_return, //should be 32
    &nitems_return, //should be 1 (zero if there is no such window)
    &bytes_left,    //should be 0 (i'm not sure but should be atomic read)
    &data           //should be non-null
);

//(return_value == Success) && nitems_return
Window win = ((Window*) data)[0];
XFree(data);
```

Useful links:

- [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/)
- [_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s03.html#idm45374033238240)

Comment: I think there is a superfluous ")" at the end of the second-to-last line

Comment: @Trevor Yep, you're right, corrected.